# Django change field for each object in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I have two models with a `ManyToMany` relationship like this:

```
# models.py

class Fileset(models.Model):
    fileset_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    in_content_build = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class ContentBuild(models.Model):
    content_build_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    filesets = models.ManyToManyField(Fileset, related_name='content_filesets')
```

When a `ContentBuild` is created I want all the `Filesets` that are in this `ContentBuild` to have their `in_content_build` field set to `True`.

I tried to achieve this by using a `post_save` signal but I have no idea how to get all the related `Filesets`.

My attempt at a signal:

```
# signals.py

@receiver(post_save, sender=ContentBuild)
def set_fileset_as_deployed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        content_build = ContentBuild.objects.get(content_build_uuid=instance.content_build_uuid)
        for fileset in content_build.filesets:
        fileset.in_content_build = True
        fileset.save()
    except ContentBuild.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

How would I be able to set `in_content_build` to `True` for all Filesets in the created `ContentBuild` instance?

Comment: I guess you're forgetting the `.all()` at your forloop. `for fileset in contet_build.filesets.all():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do what you want in a signal because `post_save` will be sent before the `filesets` is set. You should handle this wherever you are creating the instance rather than trying to do it within a signal.

```
content_build = create_content_build() # Or whatever you're using.
content_build.file_sets.set([some_fileset_queryset])
# If you can do it here, then do:
some_fileset_queryset.update(in_content_build=True)

# Otherwise:
content_build.file_sets.all().update(in_content_build=True)
```

Another thing to point out is that you're breaking normalization with this field. You could filter down to filesets that are associated with a `ContentBuild` with:

```
Fileset.objects.filter(
    content_filesets__isnull=False,
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed the `in_content_build` field and am using the filter you suggested to achieve what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `in_content_build` to be `True` by default

```
in_content_build = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**UPDATE :** If I understand you correctly, you are using `in_content_build` to check if a FileSet belongs to one of the ContentBuilds. If that's the case, you don't need that field at all. You can just use a function that will perform the check

```
class Fileset(models.Model):
    fileset_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def is_in_content_build(self):
        for cb in ContentBuild.objects.all():
            for fs in cb.filesets.all():
                if self.fileset_uuid == fs.fileset_uuid
                    return True
        return False


class ContentBuild(models.Model):
    content_build_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, 
    default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    filesets = models.ManyToManyField(Fileset, related_name='content_filesets')
```

Comment: A `Fileset` is not always part of a `ContentBuild` in my usecase.

Comment: `is_in_content_build` is not written well. You don't need to have two queries. It's also more beneficial to just show that `Fileset.objects.filter(content_filesets__isnull=False)` is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
content_build = ContentBuild.objects.get(content_build_uuid=instance.content_build_uuid)
content_build.filesets.all().update(in_content_build=True)
```